# Get instruction bytes in JIT mode, Intel Pin

Tags: assembly, pintool

I have an INS object in the instrumentation function, and I wish to get the actual bytes used to code this instruction. Looking at the INS functions, the closest I found was a function to disassemble it (show the assembly code), where I'm seeking for the actual bytes.

Assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use *[INS_Address](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#gd3b5f975c84b126531b38930b94b5544)* and *[INS_Size](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#gf031508bacfcaf4d566f9df8245f3df2)* together.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders: I did not mean the size, but rather the actual bytes used for coding it. (I also edited the question to make it clear)

Comment: I meant to read the instruction bytes from memory by using the address and size.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders: Well, this is embarrassing. The bigger lesson I learned here is that a pintool can directly access the memory region of the binary it runs. Thank you!